# Need to get project/issues from JIRA using JIRA REST API with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, jira, jira-rest-api

I am building a NodeJS application from where I want to get project/issues from JIRA using REST APIs provided by JIRA. My jira is running on some server ('http://example.com:8080/secure/Dashboard.jspa') and I am able to use REST APIs from POSTMAN using BASIC AUTH to get all kind of data but when I tried to log in to JIRA using REST APIs and NodeJS, I am getting some response but I am not able to understand it how I am going to use that information to call other APIs.

What I am doing is, I am passing username and password as a command-line args then I am sending those creds to login to JIRA. Then I am going to use the 'node-fetch' package to get information from REST APIs.

Below is my code:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const yargs = require("yargs");
var JiraClient = require("jira-connector");
var request = require("request");

const jiraBaseUrl = "http://example.com:8080/secure/Dashboard.jspa";
const loginUrl = "auth/1/session";

const username = yargs.argv.u;
const password = yargs.argv.p;
const projectName = yargs.argv.n;

var headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
};

var options = {
  url: "http://example.com:8080/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta",
  headers: headers,
  auth: {
    user: username,
    pass: password
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong or what do I need to do with the data I am getting in order to use other APIs like ('http://example.com:8080/rest/api/2/issue/10008')? Or am I doing something wrong to login?

I have read the documentation on the JIRA website but was not able to understand correctly.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @Ayush..I am not getting any specific errot but getting some big data as a JSON response..

Comment: Side note: your baseurl would be `http://example.com:8080`instead. You can find this at http://example.com:8080/secure/admin/ViewApplicationProperties.jspa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [Jira Rest API documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-rest-api-3-issue-createmeta-get), `rest/api/2/issue/createmeta` is the end point for Get create issue metadata. It "returns details of projects, issue types within projects, and, when requested, the create screen fields for each issue type for the user. " This data is supposed to be huge since it returns the details of all projects, and all issue types within projects.

If you want to use other API just change the url to the appropriate url with the correct endpoints ([documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-group-Issues)) and follow the documentation on what to send as the body data.

Here is one example of getting the details of one issue:
Put the issueIdOrKey you want to get in the brackets

```
var options = {
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'http://example.com:8080/rest/api/latest/issue/{issueIdOrKey}', 
   auth: { username: username, password: password },
   headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
   }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
   if (error) throw new Error(error);
   console.log(
      'Response: ' + response.statusCode + ' ' + response.statusMessage
   );
   console.log(body); //this would log all the info (in json) of the issue 
   // you can use a online json parser to look at this information in a formatted way

});
```